# The increment and decrement buttons functionality not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing a problem during creating the functionality of the following buttons in `React.js`. I want the functionality like this there are 2 buttons one represents increment count and the second one represents decrement count, Both of these two buttons also reset their state to default when they are clicked.

**Example:**

[image: The Buttons functionality]

**Implementation:**
I created two buttons, buttons are working fine when they are clicked, but maintaining the count state is not working correctly.

**Code:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [like, setLike] = useState(false);
  const [dislike, setDislike] = useState(false);
  const [likeCount, setLikeCount] = useState(0);
  const [dislikeCount, setDislikeCount] = useState(0);

  // Functions
  function handleLikeIncrement() {
    setLike(!like);
  }

  function handleDisLikeIncrement() {
    setDislike(!dislike);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (like) {
      setLikeCount(1);
    } else {
      setLikeCount(0);
    }

    if (dislike) {
      setDislikeCount(1);
    } else {
      setDislikeCount(0);
    }
  }, [like, dislike]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" onClick={handleLikeIncrement}>
        Smile ({likeCount})
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleDisLikeIncrement}>
        Sad ({dislikeCount})
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox link:](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-vpo10o)

[image: My Example]

What I am doing wrong in my code logic?, if there is a simple way to implement this thing I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the functionality you show cannot be built if those buttons are the only way to set likes and dislikes, because as soon as you click like, it will remove any dislikes (or take them negative), and vice versa.

If you want more standard increment/decrement behavior, you could try something like

```
export default function LikeControl() {
   const [likes, setLikes] = useState(0);
   const [dislikes, setDislikes] = useState(0);
   const handleIncrementLikes = () => {
      setLikes((likeCount) => ++likeCount);
      //don't recommend, but if you really want what you show, this is closest
      setDislikes((dislikeCount) => --dislikeCount);
   }
   const handleIncrementDislikes = () => {
      setDislikes((dislikeCount) => ++dislikeCount);
      //don't recommend, but if you really want what you show, this is closest
      setLikes((likeCount) => --likeCount);
   }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" onClick={handleIncrementLikes}>
        Smile ({likes})
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleIncrementDislikes}>
        Sad ({dislikes})
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```